# Get component text based on component name

Tags: delphi, components

So I creat some TEdit components like this

```
var
  lb : TLabel;
  topLabel, i: Integer;
  dbedit : TEdit;
begin
  inherited;
  topLabel := 40;
  i := 0;
  lb := TLabel.Create(nil);
  lb.Parent := GroupBox2;
  lb.Left := 245;
  lb.Top := 20;
  lb.Caption := 'ASD';
  with  DataModule.myStoredProc do begin
       Close;
       ParamByName('@Param1').AsInteger := 1;
       ExecProc;
       Open;
       SetLength(nrPozitiiDinctionar,RecordCount);
       First;
       while not Eof do begin
           lb := TLabel.Create(nil);
           lb.Parent := GroupBox2;
           lb.Left := 7;
           lb.Top := topLabel  ;
           lb.Caption := FieldByName('X').AsString;
           dbedit := TEdit.Create(nil);
           dbedit.Name := 'Edit'+IntToStr(FieldByName('Poz').AsInteger);
           dbedit.Text := '';
           dbedit.Parent := GroupBox2;
           dbedit.Height := 21;
           dbedit.Width := 40;
           dbedit.Left := 240;
           dbedit.Top := lb.Top-3 ;
           topLabel := topLabel + 30;
           nrPozitiiDinctionar[i] := FieldByName('Poz').AsInteger;
           i := i + 1;
           Next;
       end;

  end;

end;
```

Then after the user add his input I run a function with this code

```
 var
  IDPoz, I : Integer;
  dbedit : TEdit;
  pctj,nume : string;
   begin
      for I := Low(nrPozitiiDinctionar) to High(nrPozitiiDinctionar)  do
         begin
           nume := 'Edit'+IntToStr(nrPozitiiDinctionar[i]);
           pctj := TEdit(FindComponent('Edit'+IntToStr(nrPozitiiDinctionar[i]))).Text;
           with DateCOFurnizori.spCOFCmzFurnizoriEvaluarePozitii_Edit do begin
           ParamByName('@IDEvaluare').AsInteger := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
           ParamByName('@IDPozitie').AsInteger := IDPoz;
           ParamByName('@DictionarID').AsInteger := 9103;
           ParamByName('@DictionarPozitiiID').AsInteger := nrPozitiiDinctionar[i];
           ParamByName('@Punctaj').AsFloat :=  1 ;//StrToFloat(pctj) ;
           ParamByName('@DataEvaluare').AsDateTime := Now;
           ExecProc;
           IDPoz := IDPoz + 1;
         end;
 end;
```

This is only a portion of the code but this should relate to my problem.

When I use the debugger there is no value in pctj, what am I doing wrong? I try to get the value of the TEdits based on their names. What am I doing wrong with the FindComponent function?

Comment: You should organize the controls in a list to avoid searching by the name. Just use the index of the list.

Comment: And how can I do that? And why should I avoid searching by name?

Comment: Yeah, don't pfaff around with FindComponent. Stick your controls in an array and look them up. Far cleaner.

Comment: BTW There is no need to call `ExecProc` **and** `Open`. Just call one or the other. `Open` will execute the SP and open the returned dataset (if any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not assigning an `Owner` to the `TEdit` controls, so that is why [`FindComponent()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) cannot find them. Either assign `Self` as the Owner (since you are calling `Self.FindComponent()`), or else store the `TEdit` pointers in a `TList` or `TObjectList` that you can loop through when needed.

Comment: So what owner should I assign?

Comment: Look at the documentation - I just added the link

Comment: `FindComponent()` is a method of `TComponent`, so you have to assign the same component that you are calling `FindComponent()` on, which in your example is likely your `TForm`.

Comment: @SirRufo: you wiped out half my answer, particularly the portion where I offered an alternative. Mistake or not, you should not edit someone's answer immediately after it was posted, they may still be editing it (as I was). The the answerer some time to finish first.

Comment: It's fine to edit an answer immediately. If you want to avoid somebody editing whilst you are still writing, don't post while still writing. If you want to post when the answer is half done, as many of us do, then you take that risk.

Comment: I write a lot of my answers using a tablet, and sometimes even a phone.  Posting half-finished answers is almost a necessity, especially when writing code examples, to avoid crashing mobile browsers, and just to get ideas out since it takes longer to type on a mobile device than on a desktop.

Comment: That's fine. Me too. But then edits when the device constraints leads to typos are inevitable.